# Gnome on screen keyboard: Have different keyboard layout than hardware keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, on-screen-keyboard

I'm learning a language that doesn't use latin script and I would love to have the on screen keyboard switched to that language's keyboard layout without switching the physical keyboard on my computer to a different layout. Is that possible with the Gnome on-screen-keyboard?

Comment: What OS are you using? In Ubuntu, to add a new Gnome keyboard layot, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/875688/how-to-install-usa-international-keyboard-option-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-10 . Once you do so, both the on-screen and physical keyboard layouts can be switched from one language to another. *Caveat:* be careful that your login password can be entered in the current keyboard before locking or shutting the PC! [It's embarrassing to relate how I discovered that issue...,]

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thank you, but I try to figure out how to have the on screen keyboard for one language and the physical keyboard at the same time for another layout. So that I don't have to switch between layouts all the time. Let' say I want to input Greek with the on screen keyboard and English with the physical keyboard at the same time.

Comment: Switching layouts can be done with a single key-combination in 1/10 second. In *some* OS's, the layout can be set *per application*, so you might type in ελληνική γλώσσα in LibreOffice writer, yet in the English layout in Thunderbird email client.